# How to set initial slice state using slice reducer

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux

So, I've got a redux slice, where there are two reducers, `setTodos` and `addTodo`, the initial state is set to be empty, but soon updated using the reducer `setTodos`, the data of `setTodos`(dispatched from a component) is fetched by a network call, so it is an asynchronous task. The data is updated properly, but when I try adding a new todo, the addition is not reflected on the screen as it should, perhaps it is displayed only on reload because `setTodos` is executed again and the state is updated accordingly.

```
const myTodoSlice = createSlice({
  name:'Todo',
  initialState:{todos:[]},
  reducers:{
     addTodo:(state,action)=>{
          state.todos.push(action.payload.todo)
     },
     setTodos:(state,action)=>{
          //Approach 1 of setting the initial todo state.
          state.todos = action.payload.arrayOfTodos
          
          //Approach 2 of setting the initial todo state.
          // state.todos.push(...action.payload.arrayOfTodos)
     }
}
```

List rendering code:

```
const selector  = useSelector((arg:RootStateOrAny)=>arg.todos.todos)
return(
 <React.Fragment>
   {selector?.map((item:RootStateOrAny) => <TodoItem key={Math.random()} title={item.todoTitle} desc={item.todoDescription} />)}
 </React.Fragmnet>
)
```

Currently, I'm following approach 1, but by doing so, I'm unable to render new additions on the screen. When I tried using approach 2, I'm getting errors mostly related to re-render depth exceeded.
I'd want to know by following approach 1, why is the addition not rendered, and what changes can I make to get the desired result?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that React sees the same array reference (because the `push` is a mutation operation of the existing array instance) and ignores the rendering.
Instead of

```
     addTodo:(state,action)=>{
          state.todos.push(action.payload.todo)
     },
```

Try like below which creates a new array instance with adding the new todo item (`concat` returns a new array with the new item without mutating the existing one).

```
     addTodo:(state,action)=>{
          state.todos = state.todos.concat([action.payload.todo])
     },
```

Comment: @Prajwal Kulkarni, check this out !!

Comment: I did try a similar approach, I tried doing `state.todos = [...state.todos,action.payload.todo]`, but that didn't work, I also tried as you suggested using the `concat` method, it still isn't working.

Comment: Also, doesn't redux use `Immer` under the hood that manages reconstruction of state(s) even when we use mutation-like syntax?

Comment: can you please share the code for todo list rendering. Better if you can create a code-sandbox => https://codesandbox.io/s/new.

Comment: To get hold of the state I'm using `useSelector` hook and then mapping on the instance of the `useSelector` hook. I've added the code for the list rendering, kindly check.